# Cannot resolve method 'fromJson(org.json.JSONObject, java.lang.Class<me.myrottentomatoes.Result[]>)'

Tags: java, android, json, gson

in the method fromJson, in my class Result, I want to deserialize the JsonObject into an ArrayList of the type Result.

```
public static ArrayList<Result> fromJson(JSONObject items) {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<Result>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return results = gson.fromJson(items, Result[].class);
}
```

I can't find the solution for this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'fromJson(org.json.JSONObject, java.lang.Class<me.myrottentomatoes.Result[]>)'
```

To me it looks like I'm passing the right arguments to the method. Please help, thanks.
Here's the Result class:

```
public class Result {

@Expose
private Boolean adult;
@SerializedName("backdrop_path")
@Expose
private String backdropPath;
@SerializedName("genre_ids")
@Expose
private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("original_language")
@Expose
private String originalLanguage;
@SerializedName("original_title")
@Expose
private String originalTitle;
@Expose
private String overview;
@SerializedName("release_date")
@Expose
private String releaseDate;
@SerializedName("poster_path")
@Expose
private String posterPath;
@Expose
private Double popularity;
@Expose
private String title;
@Expose
private Boolean video;
@SerializedName("vote_average")
@Expose
private Double voteAverage;
@SerializedName("vote_count")
@Expose
private Integer voteCount;

//get's and set's...
//and the method public static ArrayList<Result> fromJson(JSONObject items)
```

Comment: It should be ArrayList.class, not Result[].class.

Comment: Android Studio is giving: Cannot resolve method 'fromJson(org.json.JSONObject, java.lang.Class<java.util.ArrayList>)'.

Comment: Your first parameter should be a string

Comment: I see, but I thought it could also be done with a JsonElement in that parameter.  
https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html

Comment: I don't see fromJson there.

Comment: Sorry! Wrong url...
https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Comment: You need to use com.google.gson.JsonObject, not org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Thanks! Didn't noticed that... I'll work it out now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `fromJson` method's first parameter is `com.google.gson.JsonObject`, not `org.json.JSONObject`.

See here: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Other thing to note is that your second parameter should be `ArrayList.class`, not `Result[].class`.