# Can't Resolve fromJson

Tags: java, android, gson

I've looked over [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453406/gson-with-mixed-read) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319222/cannot-resolve-method-fromjsonorg-json-jsonobject-java-lang-classme-myrotten) all trying to get android studio to recognize the `fromJson` method with no luck. I have `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2` as my `gson` dependency in my project structure. So, far all I've tried will still not allow this line to compile:

```
LookupRate cuRate = gson.fromJson(gson, LookupRate.class);
```

I've tried the following imports with no luck making my best effort to clean my project each time just for some kind of refresh. Imports:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
```

Should I be trying something else? I look over at what each of the two parameters should be dependent upon in [google's documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html).

Here is some context for the gson variable as I realized it was late at night when I named some of this stuff. In the `doInBackground()` method I declared a variable `gSB` like so:

```
StringBuilder gSB = new StringBuilder();
```

inside of a `try` statement it assigned like so:

```
connectStat = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
InputStream inputer = new BufferedInputStream(connectStat.getInputStream());
scanner = new Scanner(inputer);
while (scanner.hasNext()) gSB.append(scanner.nextLine());
Log.v(checkRSP, "Response(" + connectStat.getResponseCode() + "):" +
                connectStat.getResponseMessage());
```

All exceptions are handled properly then after my `try`,`catch`,`finally`. The variable `gson` is assigned like so:

```
String gson = gSB.toString();
```

Then the line where `fromJson` cannot be resolved comes next, but I will repeat it to remove any confusion my amateur description may have caused:

```
LookupRate cuRate = gson.fromJson(gson, LookupRate.class);
```

Comment: there are many fromJson overloaded function but no one take gson as a param.

Comment: its may be confuse with syntax `LookupRate cuRate = gson.fromJson(gson, LookupRate.class);` 
you need to use `LookupRate cuRate = gson.fromJson(reader, LookupRate.class);`

Comment: gson.fromJson(yourjosnString, LookupRate.class);

Comment: I may have confused the syntax, but I added more of my code to provide a little more context.

Comment: you have 2 variables with same name, `String gson = gSB.toString();` and the `Gson gson` so rename either one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first parameter `gson` is not valid

one of the overloads -which i think you are trying to use- takes a `String` that contains the JSON content.

so your code should be:

```
//assume your JSON content is stored in variable name `myJsonStr`
LookupRate cuRate = gson.fromJson(myJsonStr, LookupRate.class);
```

you just need to fill `myJsonStr` form wherever you get your data (web-service, database,local file,...etc)

Comment: let me add a little more context to the code and see if you still think that is the case.

Comment: @AustinMauldin yes you are using the one with `String` for 1st param